# Проблема с деплоем приложения spring 6 + spring-security 6 + jsf 3.0 на сервер payara 6

Tags: spring, spring-security, jsf, web.xml

После обновления библиотек (перехода на jsf 3.0, spring 6 и spring-security 6) при деплое на сервер payara 6 стала появляться ошибка:

```
    [2024-01-26T11:43:02.840+0300] [Payara 6.2022.1] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-CORE-00108] [jakarta.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=149 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1706258582840] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5772)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:619)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:958)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1813)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:361)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.initialize(ApplicationLifecycle.java:630)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:616)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:552)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:551)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:582)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:574)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:573)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1869)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1755)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:604)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1665)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:916)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:288)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5172)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:681)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5750)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:686)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.http.AuthorizationFilterParser$RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManagerFactory#0' while setting constructor argument
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:686)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
    ... 80 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.http.AuthorizationFilterParser$RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManagerFactory#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#fece8bf' of type [org.springframework.security.web.servlet.util.matcher.MvcRequestMatcher] while setting bean property 'requestMatcherMap'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBeanValue(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.lambda$resolveValueIfNecessary$1(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:152)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.lambda$resolveManagedMap$3(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:721)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedMap(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1665)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#fece8bf': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#75354eed' of type [org.springframework.security.config.http.HandlerMappingIntrospectorFactoryBean] while setting constructor argument
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBeanValue(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.lambda$resolveValueIfNecessary$1(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:152)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:686)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBeanValue(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:407)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#75354eed': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:124)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBeanValue(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:410)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' available: A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HandlerMappingIntrospectorFactoryBean.getObject(HandlerMappingIntrospectorFactoryBean.java:46)
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.HandlerMappingIntrospectorFactoryBean.getObject(HandlerMappingIntrospectorFactoryBean.java:34)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:148)
    ... 120 more
```

Основная проблема, как я понял, заключается вот в этой строке:

**No bean named 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' available: A Bean named mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector of type org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector is required to use MvcRequestMatcher. Please ensure Spring Security & Spring MVC are configured in a shared ApplicationContext.**

Мои конфигурации контекста securityJsfConfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">
 
 
    <!-- handle situation where ajax request is made when session has timed out -->
    <beans:bean id="ajaxSessionManagementFilter" class="rpk.lincor.awp.filter.JsfAjaxFilter">
        <!-- this propery value should match what is configured for session-management invalid-session-url -->
        <beans:property name="invalidSessionUrl" value="/j_spring_security_logout" />
    </beans:bean>

    <sec:http use-expressions="true" create-session="always" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/modules" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/modules/pages/error.xhtml" access="permitAll" />

        <sec:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"
                        username-parameter="j_username"
                        password-parameter="j_password"
                        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                        authentication-success-handler-ref="authSuccessHandler"
                        authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml?state=failure" />
        <sec:logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml?state=logout"
                    logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
                    invalidate-session="true" />
        <sec:access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/login.xhtml" access="! hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/" access="! hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        
        <!-- this filter added to handle situation where ajax request is made when session has timed out -->
        <sec:custom-filter ref="ajaxSessionManagementFilter" before="SESSION_MANAGEMENT_FILTER" />
        
        <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <sec:headers disabled="true"/>
    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider ref="authProvider">
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Мой applicationContext.xml (его чать):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="rpk.lincor.awp.auth" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="rpk.lincor.awp.menu" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="rpk.lincor.awp.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="rpk.lincor.awp.pages" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="rpk.ases.awp.pages" />


    <bean id="pageScope" class="rpk.lincor.awp.scope.PageScope">
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
        <property name="scopes">
            <map>
                <entry key="page">
                    <ref bean="pageScope" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <!--application pages-->
    <!-- dimension -->
    <bean id="systemPage" class="rpk.lincor.awp.menu.IrbisPage" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg name="tabId" value="system:list" />
        <constructor-arg name="name" value="Справочник систем" />
        <constructor-arg name="redirect" value="/modules/pages/dim/system/systemList.xhtml" />
        <constructor-arg name="inMenu" value="false" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="systemCreatePage" class="rpk.lincor.awp.menu.IrbisPage" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg name="tabId" value="system:create" />
        <constructor-arg name="name" value="Создание системы" />
        <constructor-arg name="redirect" value="/modules/pages/dim/system/systemCreate.xhtml" />
        <constructor-arg name="inMenu" value="false" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="systemEditPage" class="rpk.lincor.awp.menu.IrbisPage" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg name="tabId" value="system:edit" />
        <constructor-arg name="name" value="Редактирование системы" />
        <constructor-arg name="redirect" value="/modules/pages/dim/system/systemEdit.xhtml" />
        <constructor-arg name="inMenu" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

Мой web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
  <display-name>ases</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>Version</param-name>
    <param-value>1.0.0.2</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring/*.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>jakarta.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>jakarta.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>jakarta.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
  </context-param>
  
  <filter>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>encoding</param-name>
      <param-value>utf-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>pageFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>rpk.ases.awp.filter.PageServletFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>pageFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter>
    <filter-name>validFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>rpk.lincor.awp.filter.ValidationFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>validFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/modules/pages/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>



  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>rpk.ases.awp.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/modules/pages/error.xhtml?code=500</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/modules/pages/error.xhtml?code=404</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/modules/pages/error.xhtml?code=403</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.io.FileNotFoundException</exception-type>
    <location>/modules/pages/error.xhtml?code=404</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException</exception-type>
    <location>/modules/pages/error.xhtml?code=500</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.IllegalArgumentException</exception-type>
    <location>/modules/pages/error.xhtml?code=500</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>jakarta.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/modules/pages/error.xhtml?code=500</location>
  </error-page>
  <error-page>
    <exception-type>jakarta.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
    <location>/modules/pages/error.xhtml?code=500</location>
  </error-page>
</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml и securityJsfConfig.xml лежат в папке WEB-INF/spring

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С jsf2.3 и spring 5 всё запускалось. Не могу понять - что не так в моих настройках?

**ОБНОВЛЕНИЕ**
Решил проблему путем добавления в свой applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector">
    </bean>
```

Это решило проблему, но я не понимаю, почему в новой версии я должен прописывать этот бин в своём applicationContext.xml.